# Create injectable service from external class

Tags: angular

I have a library which exposes a class `HtMapClass`. It needs `mapType` as a string during construction.

```js
class HtMapClass{
  constructor(mapType: string) {}
  initMap(id: string) {}
}
```

I want to create a angular wrapper module lets say `HtModule`, which can be imported in angular app, which exposes the class `HtMapClass`

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HtModule.forRoot({mapType: 'google'})
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and now use the `HtMapClass` as a service.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public mapService: HtMapService
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.mapService);
    this.mapService.initMap('map') //this is not working
  }
}
```

To achieve this I have created `HtModule` below.

```js
export let MAP_TYPE = new InjectionToken<HtMapType>('app.mapType');

export function mapServiceFactory (mapType: HtMapType = 'google') {
  return new HtMapClass(mapType);
}

export function  forRoot (config): ModuleWithProviders {
  return {
    ngModule: HtModule,
    providers: [
      HttpClient,
      { provide: 'MAP_TYPE', useValue: config.mapType },
      {provide: HtMapService, useFactory: mapServiceFactory, deps: ['MAP_TYPE']}
    ]
  };
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpClientModule]
})
export class HtModule {
  static forRoot = forRoot;
}
```

HtMapService class looks like this

```js
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { HtMapClass, HtMapType } from "ht-js-map";

@Injectable()
export class HtMapService extends HtMapClass {
  test() {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Now when i import HtModule and inject `HtMapService`, only `this.mapService.test()` is available. I cant access other methods in `HtMapClass` class. `this.mapService.initMap('map')` is not working with error `Property 'initMap' does not exist on type 'HtMapService'`

`ht-js-map` is written in typescript
How can I fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: The setup above doesn't make much sense. Why are you extending a class if you're not using it and doing HtMapClass instead? I'm not sure what `ht-js-map` is but it likely has no TS types. It's not clear if 'I cant access other methods' addresses the fact there are no other methods, or they are actually there but TS throws errors when you use them.

Comment: ht-js-map is our internal package written in ts. All I want is the create a wrapper to inject this class, and the values required during construction provided when importing the wrapper module

Comment: It can be `export class HtMapService extends HtMapClass { constructor(@Inject('MAP_TYPE') mapType) { super(mapType) } }` and registered as `HtMapService` provider. Please, elaborate what is 'I cant access other methods'. A screenshot or other explanation that there is really no other methods could help.

Comment: How you can not access the other methods? what error are you getting?

Comment: updated the question